# How to return the row that matches a specific value in one column and the highest matching date in another (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Apps Script to attempt to go through a Google Sheets spreadsheet and carry out an action based on the latest value for a certain subset of values. For example, given the following spreadsheet:

| Code | Date | Take action? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5/30/2022 | Yes |
| b | 5/06/2022 | No |
| a | 5/31/2022 | No |

I would like the script to find the newest Date for every unique Code and take an action if and ONLY IF that newest entry for the Code has the Take action column set to "Yes". I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this and was hoping someone might be able to give me some scratch code to base off of.

I have tried using Math.max() on the Date column, extracted, but that provides me with the maximum Date in the whole column. I don't know how to set up the syntax to find the row that matches that maximum Date within a Code subset ("a", in my table).

Comment: I thought that in your question, it is required to know your actual Spreadsheet. 1. Columns of "Code", "Date", and "Take action?" are columns A, B, and C, respectively? 2. Values of column "C" are date objects? 3. About `I would like the script to find the newest Date for every unique Code and take an action if and ONLY IF that newest entry for the Code has the Take action column set to "Yes".`, how do you want to execute the script?

Answer (score 2):

```
function findWantedData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const idx = hs.reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i; return a }, {});
  const o = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    if (r[idx["TakeAction"]] == "Yes") {
      if (!a.hasOwnProperty(r[idx["Code"]])) {
        a[r[idx["Code"]]] = [[r[idx["Date"]], i + 2]];
        a.pA.push(r[idx["Code"]]);
      } else {
        a[r[idx["Code"]]].push([r[idx["Date"]], i + 2]);
        a[r[idx["Code"]]].sort((a, b) => b[0].valueOf() - a[0].valueOf());
      }
    }
    return a;
  }, { pA: [] });
  o.pA.forEach(p => {
    Logger.log(`The latest ${p} occured on ${o[p][0][0]} and it is on row ${o[p][0][1]}}`);
  });
}

Execution log
6:57:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
6:57:09 PM  Info    The latest b occured on Sun May 29 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) and it is on row 3}
6:57:09 PM  Info    The latest a occured on Tue May 24 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) and it is on row 8}
6:57:09 PM  Info    The latest c occured on Sun May 22 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) and it is on row 10}
6:57:10 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

My Data:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Code | Date | TakeAction |
| 2 | a | 5/30/2022 | No |
| 3 | b | 5/29/2022 | Yes |
| 4 | c | 5/28/2022 | No |
| 5 | a | 5/27/2022 | No |
| 6 | b | 5/26/2022 | No |
| 7 | c | 5/25/2022 | No |
| 8 | a | 5/24/2022 | Yes |
| 9 | b | 5/23/2022 | Yes |
| 10 | c | 5/22/2022 | Yes |
| 11 | a | 5/21/2022 | No |
| 12 | b | 5/20/2022 | No |
| 13 | c | 5/19/2022 | No |
| 14 | a | 5/18/2022 | No |
| 15 | b | 5/17/2022 | No |
| 16 | c | 5/16/2022 | Yes |
| 17 | a | 5/15/2022 | Yes |
| 18 | b | 5/14/2022 | Yes |
| 19 | c | 5/13/2022 | No |
| 20 | a | 5/12/2022 | No |
| 21 | b | 5/11/2022 | No |
| 22 | c | 5/10/2022 | No |

Requested References:

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Array.methds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [JavaScript.object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed response. First of all, I do not understand this code at all - do you have any online resources you could point me to to learn the general approach used here? Second, I am receiving the following Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
SendEmail.vs.reduce.pA @ sendEmail.gs:75
SendEmail @ sendEmail.gs:72
Lines 72 and 75 are, respectively (vertical bars used to signify lines), || const o = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => { || and || if (!a.hasOwnProperty(r[idx["Code"]])) { ||

Comment: I tested this on my on  data so I can't explain the cannot read properties issue because I cannot reproduce it. I don't understand you comments about sendEmail since this is the first time in your question that you mentioned.  There is no comparison between sendEmail and reduce.  sendEmail is purely Google Apps Script Server Code and reduce is a javascript array method.

Comment: The "sendEmail" is just the wrapper function I'm writing that will define the action to be taken when "Take action" is set to "Yes". What is the [hs, ...vs] command doing? I have a feeling that's where I'm doing wrong - it must be doing something strange but I don't understand what hs, vs, a, h, and i are.

Comment: It's an array literal and normally comes under the heading of destructuring.  It's a way to assign at lot of variables all at one time.  In this case the hs takes the first row and the vs takes the rest so it is a multiline variable

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up taking chunks of this and made my code work

Answer (score 1):

Cooper's solution is almost perfect except one thing. It's not for average minds.

For the less brilliant guys like me I'd propose the less perfect but more readable code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [_, ...data] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  console.log(get_last_action('a', data)); // output: No
  console.log(get_last_action('b', data)); // output: No
  console.log(get_last_action('c', data)); // output: Not found

}

function get_last_action(code, data) {
  // remove the rows with wrong codes
  data = data.filter(x => x[0] == code);

  // return if no rows
  if (data.length == 0) return 'Not found';

  // if just one row was found return the value from third cell
  if (data.lenght == 1) return data[2];

  // otherwice: make the array [timestamp, take_action],
  // sort it, get its last row, and return the value from second cell
  return data.map(x => [x[1].getTime(), x[2]]).sort().pop()[1];
}
```

Actually the second condition `if (data.length == 1)` is redundant. And if you don't need to check if the table contains the 'code' the function `get_last_action()` can be boiled down to the one-liner:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [_, ...data] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  const get_last_action = (code, data) => data.filter(x => x[0] == code)
    .map(x => [x[1].getTime(), x[2]]).sort().pop()[1];
  
  console.log(get_last_action('a', data)); // output: No
  console.log(get_last_action('b', data)); // output: No
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yuri! This is indeed very legible, and I managed to grab bits from this and bits from Cooper's code to make my code work.

Comment: Just in case, I just added the even more compact solution.